# CSS layout bug with buttons and empty content

Tags: html, css

I've got a layout bug with the snippet below in IE11, Chrome, Firefox - the second button is not correctly inline with the first button.

The problem goes away as soon as I add any non-whitespace content to the inner span on the second button.

Is there a CSS fix that will bring the buttons inline without requiring actual content, ideally without changing the rest of the CSS?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CSS Problem</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<style>
.mainBorder { padding: 20px; background-color: #254669 }
    
button {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 8px 1px 8px; 
    height: 24px;
    background-color: #254669;
    border: 1px solid #53779D;
    transition: all 150ms ease-out;
    outline: none;
}

button:disabled {
    opacity: 0.65;
}

button:enabled {
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover:enabled {
    background-color: #53779D;
}

button:active:enabled > span.content {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: translateY(-1px);
}

button:focus {
    border-color: white;
}    

button.iconButton {
    width: 24px;
    padding: 0;
}

span.icon {
    display: block;
    height: 16px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Button</h1>
    <div class="mainBorder">
        <button><span class="content">Default</span></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button class="iconButton"><span class="icon"></span></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add vertical-align:middle to button clas like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L6bd1ys5/)**

```
button {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 8px 1px 8px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: #254669;
    border: 1px solid #53779D;
    transition: all 150ms ease-out;
    outline: none;
    vertical-align:middle; /* added this */
}
```

Comment: Ah great, knew it would be something simple like that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
display: table-row;
vertical-align: middle;
```

in your `button` and

```
box-sizing: border-box;
display: table;
```

in `.mainBorder` class

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CSS Problem</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<style>

.mainBorder {
    background-color: #254669;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: table;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
    
button {
    background-color: #254669;
    border: 1px solid #53779d;
    color: white;
    display: table-row;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 24px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 0 8px 1px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 150ms ease-out 0s;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
  
button:disabled {
    opacity: 0.65;
}

button:enabled {
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover:enabled {
    background-color: #53779D;
}

button:active:enabled > span.content {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: translateY(-1px);
}

button:focus {
    border-color: white;
}    

button.iconButton {
    width: 24px;
    padding: 0;
}

span.icon {
    display: block;
    height: 16px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Button</h1>
    <div class="mainBorder">
        <button><span class="content">Default</span></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button class="iconButton"><span class="icon"></span></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need a solution that is CSS-based, the markup can't change.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to not have all the spaces if you intend to have space between elements because that is hard to manage at times but if you want to keep it the same markup this css for the .iconButton:

```
button.iconButton{
    width: 24px;
    top: 7px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

but if you want to rid yourself of the spaces then you can, optionally, the spaces would definitely affect the layout

```
button.iconButton{
    width: 24px;
    top: 3px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 15px;
}
```